# Keep drop shadows in the same direction on rotating element in CSS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, shadow

I want to create a rectangular volume rocker that can be rotated by the user and cast a vertical drop shadow that keeps facing the same direction (downwards).

However, using CSS's box-shadow on a rotating element results in a shadow that moves with it.

Is there a way to dynamically modify the direction of a box-shadow so that it stays put even if the element that casts it is rotating?

Thanks

Comment: How are you achieving rotation?

Comment: What code do you currently have? A jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I mean, I already made [one](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hvu5j/), but I don't know what a rectangular volume rocker is, so I don't know what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: @Vector: I think the OP is saying something similar to https://jsfiddle.net/v6oaoogd/2/
The only difference being that the shadow's direction must be the same at all times

Answer (score 3):

Consider the mathematics of performing rotations on Cartesian coördinates:

To convert a value in degrees, *θ*, to a rotation matrix *R*, you set *R* equal to

[image: R]

Now, consider your shadow's direction, which was set in *x* and *y* coördinates as a vector from the origin

[image: xy]

So, perform the following operation to get new coördinates *a, b* from your old coördinates *x, y*

[image: R][image: xy] = [image: Rxy] =[image]

```
function rotate(x, y, theta) {
    var a, b,
        sinTheta = Math.sin(theta),
        cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    a = x * cosTheta - y * sinTheta;
    b = y * cosTheta + x * sinTheta;
    return [a, b];
}
```

You may want to negate *theta* and perhaps *y* to make everything match up with the way you want it rendered. Remember that *JavaScript* works in *radians*, so to convert degrees *d* into radians *r*

[image]

Now you just have to set your shadow to the new coördinates *a* and *b*.